# How to fix: "AttributeError: 'Class' object has no attribute 'rect'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making walls on the screen so my player sprite cannot go past them. I think I have done all the `.get_rect()` but I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: Argument must be rect style object

```
def apartment_movement():

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    boundary = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(scarn, apartment_walls, False, False)

    if boundary:
        scarn.left = False
        scarn.right = False
        scarn.up = False
        scarn.down = False
        scarn.standing = False
        scarn.sleeping = False
    if not boundary:
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and scarn.x > 110 - scarn.width - scarn.vel:  # allows the player to move left
            scarn.x -= scarn.vel
            scarn.left = True
            scarn.right = False
            scarn.up = False
            scarn.down = False
            scarn.standing = False
            scarn.sleeping = False
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and scarn.x < 795 - scarn.width - scarn.vel:  # allows the player to move right
            scarn.x += scarn.vel
            scarn.right = True
            scarn.left = False
            scarn.up = False
            scarn.down = False
            scarn.standing = False
            scarn.sleeping = False
        elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and scarn.y > 130 - scarn.height - scarn.vel:
            scarn.y -= scarn.vel
            scarn.up = True
            scarn.right = False
            scarn.left = False
            scarn.down = False
            scarn.standing = False
            scarn.sleeping = False
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and scarn.y < 540 - scarn.height - scarn.vel:
            scarn.y += scarn.vel
            scarn.down = True
            scarn.right = False
            scarn.left = False
            scarn.up = False
            scarn.standing = False
            scarn.sleeping = False
        else:  # clarifies the player is not moving left or right
            scarn.walkCount = 0


class apartment_walls(pygame.sprite.Sprite):  # creates the walls of the apartment (1st scene)

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.boundary1 = pygame.Rect(243, 60, 8, 275)
        self.boundary2 = pygame.Rect(510, 60, 8, 275)
        self.boundary3 = pygame.Rect(243, 421, 215, 5)
        self.boundary4 = pygame.Rect(243, 330, 220, 5)
        self.boundary5 = pygame.Rect(510, 421, 145, 5)
        self.boundary6 = pygame.Rect(510, 330, 145, 5)
        self.boundary7 = pygame.Rect(700, 421, 57, 5)
        self.boundary8 = pygame.Rect(700, 330, 57, 5)
        self.boundary9 = pygame.Rect(43, 410, 120, 10)
        self.boundary10 = pygame.Rect(510, 335, 5, 90)
        self.boundary11 = pygame.Rect(460, 335, 5, 90)
        self.boundary12 = pygame.Rect(700, 335, 5, 90)
        self.boundary13 = pygame.Rect(650, 335, 5, 90)


def draw_apartment():  # draws the apartment (1st scene)

    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    win.blit(bed, (322, 120))

    pygame.draw.rect(win, black, (200, 470, 100, 10), 0)
    pygame.draw.polygon(win, black, [(180, 473), (200, 488), (200, 458)], 0)

    scarn.draw(win)


class Scarn(pygame.sprite.Sprite):  # creates attributes for Michael Scarn (player)

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # loads sprites for animations
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Forward Standing.png')), pygame.Rect(
            pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Backward Standing.png')), pygame.Rect(
            [pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Up 1.png'), pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Up 2.png')]), [
                        pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Down 1.png'), pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Down 2.png')], [
                        pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Right 1.png'), pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Right 2.png'),
                        pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Right 3.png'),
                        pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Right 4.png')], [pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Left 1.png'),
                                                                          pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Left 2.png'),
                                                                          pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Left 3.png'),
                                                                          pygame.image.load(
                                                                              'Michael Scarn Left 4.png')], pygame.image.load(
            'Michael Scarn Sleeping.png')
```

Comment: `pygame.draw.rect()` is used to draw rectangle on screen, not to create object `pygame.Rect()` or keep wall's data. But actually `pygame.draw.rect()` returns `pygame.Rect()` so you don't have to use get_rect` - and you can't - `self.boundary14_rect  = pygame.draw.rect()`

Comment: So what should I do instead?

Comment: `Scarn` doen't have `rect` and you have to create it `self.rect = ...` in `__init___`

Comment: what should I write for the ...?

Comment: if all walls are similar then you can keep as list with `[x,y,width, height]` or as list with `pygame.Rect(x,y,width, height)`.

Comment: `self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)`

Comment: But I thought my issue was with Scarn

Comment: You issue is becuse you didn't create `self.rect` in `Scarn`

Comment: it is place for comments and they doesn't have to resolve main problem. Below is place for answers which should give solution for main problem.

Comment: I know but I don't know what I should write for self.rect

Comment: `self.rect` has to use `pygame.Rect()` to keep `Sprite` position and size. `self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)`

Comment: My walls aren't the same size though

Comment: because your walls are incorrect. Sprite should keep information about one object - like one wall, one player, one enemy. And then every Sprite should have one `self.rect`. `spritecollide()` use `self.rect` from two `Sprites` to check collision.

Comment: self.boundary1 = pygame.Rect(243, 60, 8, 275) should be one wall and I should do that for every wall?

Comment: Every wall should be separated `Sprite` and you should keep all walls in `pygame.sprite.Group`. There is method to check collision between two groups. One group can be group of walls, and other group can be group only with player

Comment: I changed my code up top, is that what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: Now the error is: 
TypeError: Argument must be rect style object

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information. And it shows which line makes problem.

Comment: pygame.Rect() is used to keep `x,y,width,height` not to keep image - `Rect(pygame.image.load(...))`. Normally you create list with all images and assign  current displayed image to `self.image = pygame.image.load()` or `sself.image = self.all_images[current_index]` and its size to `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()`. When you have sprites in group then you can use one command `group.draw()` to draw all sprites at once. Group will use `self.image` and `self.rect` from every sprite to blit them. To animate you assign next image to `self.image` and `group.draw()` will display different image.

Comment: But I still don't know how to make the collision

Comment: Is there any way for me to contact you directly because I really have no idea what I'm doing

Comment: you make too much new things at once. You should make game without animation  at start. Only walls and collisions.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the tips, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There were many problems in code so it is hard to describe all changes.

This is not ideal solution but at least it works.

It checks collision with walls and it draws animation (dots in different colors) when it moves down.

```
import pygame
import os
import sys

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

# folder with script
HOME = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
print('HOME:', HOME)

# subfolder with images
#RESOURCE = os.path.join(HOME, 'resource')
RESOURCE = '.'
print('RESOURCE:', RESOURCE)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED   = (255, 0, 0)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

# --- classes --- (CamelCaseNames)

class Scarn(pygame.sprite.Sprite):  # creates attributes for Michael Scarn (player)

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__() # pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # loads sprites for animations
        self.animations = {
            'forward': [
                #pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'Michael Scarn Forward Standing.png')),
                pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'dot-1.png')),
            ],
            'backward': [
                #pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'Michael Scarn Backward Standing.png')),
                pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'dot-1.png')),
            ],
            'up': [
                #pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'Michael Scarn Up 1.png')),
                #pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'Michael Scarn Up 2.png')),
                pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'dot-1.png')),
            ],
            'down': [
                #pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'Michael Scarn Down 1.png')),
                #pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'Michael Scarn Down 2.png')),
                pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'dot-1.png')),
                pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'dot-2.png')),
                pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'dot-3.png')),
            ],
            'right': [
                #pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'Michael Scarn Right 1.png')),
                #pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'Michael Scarn Right 2.png')),
                #pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'Michael Scarn Right 3.png')),
                #pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'Michael Scarn Right 4.png')),
                pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'dot-1.png')),
            ],
            'left': [
                #pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'Michael Scarn Left 1.png')),
                #pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'Michael Scarn Left 2.png')),
                #pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'Michael Scarn Left 3.png')),
                #pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'Michael Scarn Left 4.png')),
                pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'dot-1.png')),
            ],
            'sleep': [
                #pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'Michael Scarn Sleeping.png'))
                pygame.image.load(os.path.join(RESOURCE, 'dot-1.png')),
            ]
        }
         
        # current state of animation
        self.frame = 0 # frame for animation
        self.state = 'forward'
        self.moving = False
        
        # current image and position
        self.image = self.animations[self.state][self.frame]          
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        # instead of self.state ???
        self.state_left = False
        self.state_right = False
        self.state_up = False
        self.state_down = False
        self.state_standing = False
        self.state_sleeping = False
           
        self.is_collide = False
        self.vel = 5
        
    def draw(self, screen):
        self.image = self.animations[self.state][self.frame]          
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
                 
    def update(self):
        # next frame of animation
        if self.moving:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame >= len(self.animations[self.state]):
                self.frame = 0

    def check_collisions(self, walls):
        
        self.is_collide = False

        for wall in walls:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall):
                self.is_collide = True
                if self.state == 'left':
                    #self.rect.x += self.vel
                    self.rect.left = wall.right
                elif self.state == 'right':
                    #self.rect.x -= self.vel
                    self.rect.right = wall.left
                elif self.state == 'up':
                    #self.rect.y += self.vel
                    self.rect.top = wall.bottom
                elif self.state == 'down':
                    #self.rect.y -= self.vel
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.top
                break

    def handle_event(self, event=None):
        # instead of def apartment_movement():

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        self.moving = True
        
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            if self.rect.left - self.vel >= 0 :  # allows the player to move left
                self.rect.x -= self.vel
                if self.state != 'up':
                    self.state = 'up'
                    self.frame = 0
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            if self.rect.right + self.vel <= SCREEN_WIDTH:  # allows the player to move right
                self.rect.x += self.vel
                if self.state != 'right':
                    self.state = 'right'
                    self.frame = 0
        elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            if self.rect.top - self.vel >= 0:
                self.rect.y -= self.vel
                if self.state != 'up':
                    self.state = 'up'
                    self.frame = 0
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]: 
            if self.rect.bottom + scarn.vel <= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
                self.rect.y += self.vel
                if self.state != 'down':
                    self.state = 'down'
                    self.frame = 0
        else: # clarifies the player is not moving left or right
            self.walk_count = 0
            self.moving = False
            
# --- functions --- (lower_case_names)
    
def draw_apartment(win):  # draws the apartment (1st scene)

    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    win.blit(bed, (322, 120))

    pygame.draw.rect(win, BLACK, (200, 470, 100, 10), 0)
    pygame.draw.polygon(win, BLACK, [(180, 473), (200, 488), (200, 458)], 0)

    for wall in all_walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, BLACK, wall)

    scarn.draw(win)

# --- main ---

# - init -

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

# - objects -

all_walls = [
    pygame.Rect(243, 60, 8, 275),
    pygame.Rect(510, 60, 8, 275),
    pygame.Rect(243, 421, 215, 5),
    pygame.Rect(243, 330, 220, 5),
    pygame.Rect(510, 421, 145, 5),
    pygame.Rect(510, 330, 145, 5),
    pygame.Rect(700, 421, 57, 5),
    pygame.Rect(700, 330, 57, 5),
    pygame.Rect(43, 410, 120, 10),
    pygame.Rect(510, 335, 5, 90),
    pygame.Rect(460, 335, 5, 90),
    pygame.Rect(700, 335, 5, 90),
    pygame.Rect(650, 335, 5, 90),
]

scarn = Scarn(0, 0)

bg = pygame.surface.Surface((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
bg.fill(WHITE)

bed = pygame.surface.Surface((10, 20))
bed.fill(RED)

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:

    # - events -
        
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    scarn.handle_event()

    # - updates -

    scarn.check_collisions(all_walls)
    
    scarn.update() # update animation
    
    # - draws -
                    
    draw_apartment(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
    
    clock.tick(30) # 30 FPS
    
# - end -
    
pygame.quit()
```

[image] dot-1.png

[image] dot-2.png

[image] dot-3.png

Comment: *"There was many problems in code so it is hard to describe all changes."* - Is not an answer. Maybe it helps the questioner to solve his issue without any understanding how it works, but it is not any help for anyone else.

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes, it can't be useful for others but this question and code may not be clear for others too and maybe it should be closed. OR maybe I should forget this question. I wrote many comments to help but there is no place to put long code which could help with all problems so I decided to put it in answer. For others I could only write: "problem is in `pygame.Rect(pygame.image.load()` - `Rect()` needs x,y,widht,height instead of image" but probably it wouldn't resolve OP problems with all code. It would only create new questions "how to fix" but this need longer code (useless for others).